# Make this C# SwapBytes code x64 compatible

Tags: c#, memory, 64-bit

Here is a piece of code borrowed from the "Endogine" engine. It is supposed to swap the byte order of any byte array :

```
unsafe protected void SwapBytes(byte* ptr, int nLength)
{
    for(long i = 0; i < nLength / 2; ++i) {
        byte t = *(ptr + i);
        *(ptr + i) = *(ptr + nLength - i - 1);
        *(ptr + nLength - i - 1) = t;
    }
}
```

It seems to fail when I target the x64 architecture, but I can't figure why, since no pointer is cast to int32.
Any help ?

Comment: Have you tried using an int type for both nLength and i? Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: if you could run a specific sequence of bytes through (for instance, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04) on both x86 and x64 and show the results not matching, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what way does it seem to fail? It seems pretty straight forward. I would use two pointers to make it a bit faster:

```
unsafe protected void SwapBytes(byte* ptr, int nLength) {
  byte* ptr2 = ptr + nLength - 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < nLength / 2; i++) {
    byte t = *ptr;
    *ptr = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = t;
    ptr++;
    ptr2--;
  }
}
```

However, the compiler is pretty good at optimising loops and array accesses. It's likely that managed code to do the same performs pretty close to the unsafe code:

```
protected void SwapBytes(byte[] data) {
  for(int i = 0, j = data.Length - 1; i < data.Length / 2; i++, j--) {
    byte t = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = t;
  }
}
```